# Responsive units not really working

Tags: wordpress, css, responsive-design

I am working on a page that I'm trying to make responsive. I'm using background images and trying to lay them out one under the other but when adding the margin-top property using responsive units (vh, em, rem, %) my background image moves but there's a big variation on where the images should be on a laptop screen and an Ipad screen.

LINK: 
http://dbtest.destinationballybunion.ie/?page_id=3733

As I've said I tried using all the responsive units and i keep getting the same variation in results. Is there a way this can be fixed without using media queries ?

PS I am using a drag and drop Wordpress plugin called Visual Composer

CSS FOR THE PAGE:

```
#container {
    margin: 0%;
}

#container text area {
    margin: 5%;
}

wrapper {
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px; 
    margin-bottom: 0px; 
}

entry {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    padding: 0px;
}

entry-header.style {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}

.entry-content a img, #attachment-nav a img {
    background: none repeat scroll transparent;
    border: 0px solid #EEEEEE;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0px #EEEEEE;
    max-width: 98.5%;
    padding: 0%;
}

.entry-content a:hover img, #attachment-nav a:hover img {
    background: transparent repeat scroll 0 0;
}

.entry-title {
   display:none;
}

.single .entry, .page .entry, .error404 .entry {
    margin-bottom: 5.1% !important;
    padding: 0;
}

#site-title {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
} 

#site-title, #site-description {
    line-height: 100%;
}

#site-title {
    margin: 0 0;
}

#site-title img {
    margin: 0;
}

#site-title img {
    padding: 0;
}

#access {
    position: relative;
    margin-top:-0.5%;
}

.tearhist {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.tearhist {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -11.000em;
    z-index: 100;
}

.tearytext {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 2.500em;
    margin-right: 2.500em;
}

.tearytext h4 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-size: 1.100em;
    line-height: 100%;
}

.histmainb {
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.histmainb {
    position: relative;
}

.histblocka {
    background-image: url('http://dbtest.destinationballybunion.ie/wp-content/uploads   
/2014/10/HISTOBACK-1-SMALL.png');
    background-size: auto auto;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.histblocka {
    position: absolute;
}

.histblocka p {
    margin-right: 23.000em;
    margin-left: 3.500em;
}

.histblocka h2 {
    margin-top: 3.500em;
    margin-left:  3.000em;
}

.histblocka h2 {
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #666;
}

.histblocka p {
    font-size: 1.000em;
}

.histblocka h2 {
    font-size: 1.000em;
}

.nublockb {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 21.000em;
}

.nublockb {
    background-image: url('http://dbtest.destinationballybunion.ie/wp-content/uploads 
/2014/10/HISTOBACK-3-SMALL.png');
    background-size: auto auto;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: I think there is no way if you didnt use the media queries

Comment: thanks for the reply. I know media queries would be the ideal solution - is there a way to add a specific media query to an element through a class ? I've tried doing this but it didn't seem to work for me.